# How to create a date range filter but using odata to build a filter string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, odata, spfx

I'm creating a filter tool to filter a SharePoint list. I need to create a Start Date and Completion Date to add to an already existing filter string. Here's what I've got (I've reduced the amount of example code!):

```
 const _changeStartDate = (date: Date | null | undefined): void => {
        setStartDate(date);
        _RunFilter(null, null, date.toISOString(), null);
    };

    const _changeCompletionDate = (date: Date | null | undefined): void => {
        setCompletionDate(date);
        _RunFilter(null, null, null, date.toISOString());
    };

  const buildFilterString = (
        id: string,
        title: string,
        obu: string,
        status: string,
        startDte: string,
        compDte: string
    ) => {
        const filters = [];

       if (startDte || compDte) {
            let dateFilter: string = "";
            let strtDate: string = "";
            let compDate: string = "";
            strtDate = "StartDate ge '" + startDte + "'";
            compDate = "CompletionDate le '" + compDte + "'";
            if (strtDate !== null && compDate !== null) {
                dateFilter = strtDate + ' and ' + compDate;
            }

            filters.push(dateFilter);
        }

      /// More filter strings....

        return filters.join(' and ');
    };
```

The Start Date and Comp Date work individually, but as said, how would I get them to work together to build a date range string? This outputs only

Answer (score 0):

Try to use datetime() like this:

```
(Modified ge datetime'2022-08-10T00:00:00.000Z') and (Modified le datetime'2022-08-10T23:59:00.000Z')
```

Also you should be using Date format like this with 000Z at the end.

Comment: The .toISOString() provide that.

Comment: Yes and did datetime() helped?